# Linking Tags to Campaigns data via the Rest

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, campaign, tag

I'm trying to create a data feed that we can use to link Email Names, Campaigns, and campaign Tags together to reduce our time to insight. I've got almost all of the data I need using the REST API but I'm missing something that can retrieve the linked Tags (which I can see against the campaign when I manually check) to the campaigns.

Feel like a campaign tags should appear as a Campaign Asset but that doesn't appear to be the case - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/getCampaignAssetCollection.html

If anyone knows where I could find this it would be greatly apricated.

Thanks!